# What am I doing wrong: Constraintlayout inside ScrollView in Android Studio not scrolling to the end

Tags: java, android-studio, scrollview, android-constraintlayout, constraintlayout-barrier

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have read most of the samples I could find on YouTube and other places and tried the solutions they gave, but have not been able to resolve my issue.

The issue is that I am using `ConstraintLayout` inside `ScrollView`. I try to scroll, it does not really scroll at all. Therefore, some elements at the bottom are not shown. Below is my code. What am I doing wrong?

The below code is edited to include the corrections given and it is still not working. I really appreciate you suggestions and your intentions to help.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrolvw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"



    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

        android:id="@+id/constLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".RegisterActivity">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/regAppLogo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/fambuk_logo"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/firstNameInputLayout"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:0.45"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/fambuklogo"
            tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/firstNameInputLayout"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="280dp"

            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:hint="First name"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lastnameInputLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/regAppLogo">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/firstNameEditText"
                style="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:height="48dp"

                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="5:1"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/lastnameInputLayout"
            style="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:hint="Last name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/userNameInputLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstNameInputLayout">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/lastNameEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/userNameInputLayout"
            style="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:hint="Username"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/emailLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lastnameInputLayout">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/userNameEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/emailLayout"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:hint="Email"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/passInputLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userNameInputLayout">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/passInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailLayout">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/passEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="36dp"

                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passInputLayout"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-2dp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:text="Sign up"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passInputLayout"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Already have an account ?"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Sign in"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.473"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="255dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:text="By signing up you agree with our terms and conditions"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: Screenshot of what shows up from the code]

Comment: Can you try adding the following to the `ScrollView`: `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` 
`android:scrollbars="vertical"` and let me know if it works?

Comment: Your new layout works OK in my emulator. Is something else happening with the layout? Without further information, I don't think anyone will be able to assist you. Posting a sample project that exhibits the problem may help.

Comment: I used 2.7 QVGA emulator to get the small screen size phone effect. Which emulator did you use ? Are there emulators that have compatibility problem with scrollview or scrolling effects?  I am very new in using android studio or into developing android app, so pardon some of my questions if they sound basic  ?

Comment: I was using a Nexus 5 emulator but I tried you 2.7 QVGA emulator and I still get a full scroll. Something else is going on that is not evident from your question. Can you post what you are seeing? Maybe that will give a clue.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think it is good to know that you are not experiencing any problem from your side. I have just uploaded a screenshot of my android studio working environment.  let me know if it helps or not and we see what next to do.

Comment: Could it be a code missing in the themes, gradle or manifest ? Some code I may need to add that I have not done ?

Comment: You layout now has all constraints defined. I can't reproduce the scrolling issue, so I have nothing further to add.

Comment: I've tried the above XML on the same emulator that you are using with `API 28`. I recommend you start a new project and only add the above and see if it works or not. If it does work then, you have to compare or complete working on the new project!

Answer (score 0):

The *TextViews* "textView2", "textView3" and "textView4" do not have vertical constraints. They probably look OK in the Android Studio designer because they have  `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="420dp"` set. That setting only has value in the designer and has no effect when the app is run. Without a vertical contraint, the view will shift to the top.

Make sure all of your view have horizontal and vertical constraints set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All the TextViews had both vertical and horizontal constraints. I removed it to try some other solutions while I sent the initial post here. I forgot to add it before sending the post. But I already did that and it did not work.

Comment: Post the XML that is not working with the constraints set.

Comment: Still not working after I added the constraints in the Textviews and also included android:fitsSystemWindows="false". Above is the edited code.